# Html anchor linking and hashbang, simple solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, hashbang

I have in http://www.g3eo.com/#!/page_About the following in line 96:

```
<li><a href="#!/page_Services">Side scan sonar surveys</a></li>
```

and need to create an anchor to go to line 180:

```
<li id="sidescan"><strong>Side scan sonar surveys</strong></li>
```

I understand that to get this working I would need to do:

```
<li><a href="#!/page_Services#sss">Side scan sonar surveys</a></li>
<li id="sidescan"><a name="sss"><strong>Side scan sonar surveys</strong></a></li>
```

But this does nothing. I was wondering if the problem is the hashbang in `#!/page_Services`, without it the web page stops working properly.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't have multiple hashes in a url. At best, the browser will escape the second hash, at worst the URL will break. In this instance, as you're using the hashbang for your web-app, you'll need to roll your own version of the scroll-to-line using javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, how could I do what you explain? not really sure what you mean about rolling my own version of the scroll-to-line using javascript.

Comment: @Gery If you type `yoursite.com/#!page_Services#sss` directly in the address bar of a new tab, I know the `#sss` part won't work, but does your site work properly? If so, I might have a solution. Please tell me before I start working on it.

Comment: @blex Thanks for the suggestion, yeap the site works properly with the #sss but it doesn't redirects to the #sss section. I will check your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started working on a solution very similar to @Liam Egan's, which is good, but I thought *"What if someone wants to share a link to an anchor tag? I'll just try using both a hashbang and an anchor hash in the URL!"*.

After multiple tests, as it turns out, it's really hard to maintain, especially if you use an external library which uses the hash. It will break, so I abandoned that idea.

Here is a solution for clicks on links, which I tested on your website:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e){
        // Get the hashes in link
        var h = this.href.split('#');
        // If the first hash is not a hashbang or if there are several hashes
        if(h[1].indexOf('!') !== 0 || h.length > 2) {
            // Prevent default behavior of the link so it does not break the site
            e.preventDefault();
            // If the first hash is a hashbang (but there are multiple hashes),
            // only include the first one in the page URL
            if(h[1].indexOf('!') === 0) { window.location.hash = '#' + h[1]; }
            // Get the element with the right ID (last hash) and its scrolling container
            var el = $('#' + h.pop()), cont = el.closest('div[class^="scroll"]');
            // Scroll the scrolling container to that element after a delay,
            // because it does not work during the page transition
            setTimeout(function() {
                cont.scrollTop(0) // Reset it first to get the right position below
                    .scrollTop( el.position().top );
            },500);
        }
    });
});
```

I had to adapt it for two reasons:

- Not the whole document should scroll, just your wrapping `.scroll` div
- The scrolling won't work during page transition, so it needs a delay

It does not affect links such as `#!/page_XXX`, and will work with links such as `#myID` or `#!/page_XXX#myID`.

Finally, for simplicity, since you are using jQuery, I did too. Place that piece of code anywhere on your page after loading jQuery, and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this, ultimately I don't know how fragile having multiple hashes in a URL would be. Definitely worth a try, but I'd test extensively.

Comment: As @LiamEgan says, this hack of having 2 hashes is unknown to us, and might break some features. If you do want to use it, you'll have to do some heavy testing on different browsers/devices. So if sharing links to anchors is not important to you, you should use Liam's answer.

Comment: @blex after trying Liam's code the menu doesn't work, please take a look http://www.g3eo.com, where and how should I use your code?

Comment: @Gery, I've done some tests on your website, and edited my answer. Try it out, and see if it works for you

Comment: Yeah good edit. We were both operating under the assumption that you'd take what we'd put together and adapt to your needs.

Comment: @blex your last edit did the trick so thanks! I updated my code in http://www.g3eo.com for more testing if needed, I also modified the title of this post with the word `hashbang`, it seems to me that this caused the whole issue.

Comment: I just found that href="#close" stops working with the edited code, I thought it applies only to href with a hashbang.

Comment: @Gery Oh, good thing you found that. Those `#close` links are treated by that code as anchor links, but they are not. What you could do is remove `h[1].indexOf('!') !== 0 ||` from the first condition, leave these `#close` links as they are, and whenever you have a real anchor link, make sure to include the hashbang for it to be treated by this code

Answer (score 4):

Something like this will work:

```
// Run the code on page load. Change this to whatever your page callback is
window.addEventListener('load', function(e)
{
  // Find any of the anchors that have a hash link.
  // Change document to whatever the container is for your new elements
  as = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
  as.forEach(function(a)
  {
    a.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
      // This stops the hash being added to the URL on click
      e.preventDefault();

      // Find the hash and the target element (based on ID)
      var hash = e.target.href.split('#')[1];
      var targetEl = document.getElementById(hash);

      // Scroll the window to the target elements offsetTop
      window.scrollTo(0, targetEl.offsetTop);
    });
  });
});
```

But you'll need to run this code after the content that you want to use is loaded (rather than on page load).

Basically, this simulates hash linking without adding the hash to the url. See here for a working version - https://plnkr.co/edit/mubdlfjuFTgLeYq6ZpCR?p=preview

Comment: I just tested your code but the menu doesn't work, I tested it well at the end of my html close to the body tag and at the top of it, please take a look http://www.g3eo.com